# An Excel formula, find maximum and check for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-conditions, vba

I asked a similar question before this but it turned out that whatever formula I was using does not give me the correct result. So I have to reask the question and make it more specific.

Suppose I have the following spreadsheet:

[image]

I want a formula which gives me the latest date that have percentage change that is greater than zero and "Orange" is not mentioned in the "Comments" column. Only 1 of the percentage changes (Column Pct1 to Pct 5) needs to be >0. So the formula will output 11/20/2012 since it has % change that is greater than 0% and it is non-Orange.

I tried match, offset, max but it didnt give me the correct result. I am hoping to input this as a formula into VBA because I have a total of 20 excel files that I need to have the macro to check against. Please help me! Thanks!!

Comment: before posting please check the FAQ with instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and a personal favorite of mine: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried

Comment: I apologize if I am not specific enough. Please let me know if you don't understand my question. Thanks

Comment: Your question Title asks for a formula, but in your question you ask for VBA code...

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning in the content. I am open to VBA as well if that is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

```
{=MAX((B2:F6>0)*(ISERR(FIND("ORANGE",UPPER(G2:G6))))*(A2:A6))}
```

Enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter. Don't type the curly braces, Excel will insert them if you enter as an array formula.

The first section returns a matrix of TRUEs and FALSEs based on whether the percentages are greater than zero.

The second section returns TRUEs and FALSES based on whether FINDing "Orange" generates an error.

The last section returns an array of the dates.

When you multiply the arrays/matrices the TRUEs are 1, the FALSEs are 0 and you end up with an array of dates where all the conditions are TRUE. Finally, MAX picks the largest.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Last question: Suppose I want to exclude pineapple as well. I modified the formula into the following. However, it didnt give me the correct result. I modified Find("orange",upper(G2:G6)) into Find(or("Orange","Pineapple"), upper(G2:G6)). What did I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: To exclude "Orange" and "Pineapple" try this version `=MAX((B2:F6>0)*ISERR(SEARCH("Orange",G2:G6))*ISERR(SEARCH("Pineapple",G2:G6))*A2:A6)` - you can add more with the same pattern but if there are multiple values to exclude then a different approach might work better

Comment: @Siddharth Rout: Thanks for helping out the last week :)